# Springboot ExceptionHandler catch from Client

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

I develop a Spring Boot project and I use ExceptionHandler to catch all exceptions with `@RestControllerAdvice` annotation.
There is no problem on Server side to catch exception.
However, I don't know how to catch these exceptions in client application.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: What client are you using? RestTemplate?

Comment: yes it s RestTemplate

Comment: Then just use try - catch block when using RestTemplate. Catch RestClientException and handle it as needed.

Comment: Thanks Gondy, it will work  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [spring-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web)'s `RestTemplate`, here's an example:

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(url, String.class);
    System.out.println("Response: " + response.getBody());
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    System.err.println("Problem querying " + url + ". " + 
        "Status code " + e.getStatusCode() + 
        " and error message " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

Note that `RestTemplate` throws an exception by default for error status codes, so you need to catch `HttpStatusCodeException`.

Not all errors are `HttpStatusCodeException` though, but all of them have `RestClientException` as parent and you can also catch it if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you are, presumably, using a HTTP client (such as Spring's `RestTemplate` or Apache Commons' `HttpClient`). Something like this, perhaps:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

Given this code, the HTTP status and the response body are available as follows:

```
HttpStatus httpStatus = response.getStatusCode(); 
String responseBody = response.getBody();
```

So, whatever status code and response body you supplied via your `RestControllerAdvice` can be read out of the response.

A typical approach would be to assess whether the HttpStatus is a `200` and if it is not then fall into an exception handling block, using the response body to understand the nature of the exception.

Comment: Thanks Glitch, your solution  saves my day.